# Hiding inner faces of transparent object in render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I have an animation of an object in Alembic format. The object is a tetrahedral mesh. Thus it has inner faces. I want to render it as half transparent object. However I want to hide the inner faces in render. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: By inner faces, do you mean faces that are facing "away" that can be seen through the semi-transparent mesh? Like do you mean the outer faces of the opposite side are visible, or do you mean more like a mesh within a mesh scenario?

Comment: It is a cube which has lots of inner faces like this one: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRes4-KCwER-PjmR6qOnoIHR_L4wKzk2sANBA&usqp=CAU

Comment: you can create vertex groups and mask them with the Mask modifier

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the outer faces and assign them a vertex group:

[image]

Then give your object a *Mask* modifier with the group as *Vertex Group*:

[image]

Comment: It is weird but I cannot only assign the outer faces. The inner faces are automatically assigned. If I select outer faces and assign them to a group, the inner faces are also automatically assigned. This is the object if you want to try: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wG2UK6a1hHHC0D5eYv7P6tY3p_V1o6y1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yes because actually all your inner faces are made of vertices that are part of the outer surface, and therefore part of the vertex group, so in your particular case my solution won't work